# How to modify http headers

Tags: automation, http-headers, protractor

I am in process of automating UI test. API's are secured by oAuth. So to hit URL lets say http://mydom/api/welcome
Browser must have set with Authorization key as header and value must be valid token.

For manual testing, I use [Requestly (Chrome Extension)](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/requestly/mdnleldcmiljblolnjhpnblkcekpdkpa) to set header.
(Can anybody point me what requestly internally do so that each request from chrome get header value what was set by requestly?)

Is there any way to set header value programmatically?

PS: I used curl to call oath url to get valid token and set token value as env variable. Also i used postman to get the same. But all these does not affect when called from browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use [supertest](https://www.npmjs.com/package/supertest) and [supertest-as-promised](https://www.npmjs.com/package/supertest-as-promised) for API testing via Protractor. So I do a GET on my OAuth endpoint, store the token in a variable, then in the rest of my API calls, do `request.get(url).set('Authorization', auth.tokenType + ' ' + auth.token);`.

So one way you might be able to do this is use something like supertest to get a token, and then `browser.manage().addCookie()` to set it in your browser session.

Answer (score 1):

You can't very easily do this because Chrome does not support it (see https://github.com/seleniumhq/selenium-google-code-issue-archive/issues/141).

Personally, I would do this test using something like request (https://github.com/request/requesthttps://github.com/request/request) and basic assertions rather than through the browser with protractor.

Comment: @Viad thank you for your suggestion. One thing: I have to automate UI testing and currently using protractor framework to do this. So is there any way to integrate https://github.com/request/request with protractor?

Comment: Just put it in a protractor spec then, I guess. Make sure to wrap requests in the protractor promise implementation as it will only wait for protractor promises to complete. Still, it's like using a fork to eat soup by holding a spoon over it :p

Answer (score 1):

You cannot manipulate http headers directly in selenium. You need to use a proxy to do such things. [BrowserMobProxy](https://github.com/lightbody/browsermob-proxy) is a popular proxy in selenium world. You can use the node wrapper [browsermob-node](https://github.com/zzo/browsermob-node) to do this in protractor test. I added a sample section on how to modify headers [here](https://github.com/zzo/browsermob-node#gory-details)

Comment: thank you for the response. Will try use it and let you know if it works.

Answer (score 0):

@Sam Requestly Author here.

No currently, you can not programatically set a header value. It has to be static for now. This is very long term plan to implement this feature, given how many use cases come up. But here is what you can do.

You can fork [Requestly github repo](https://github.com/requestly/chrome-extension). The code where actual header modification happens is inside [Background.js](https://github.com/requestly/chrome-extension/blob/master/src/background/background.js) . Method name is `BG.Methods.modifyHeaders`. Please go ahead and write your own logic to generate header value and modify it.

A note from [Chrome Docs](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest)

> The following headers are currently not provided to the onBeforeSendHeaders event. This list is not guaranteed to be complete nor stable.

- Authorization
- Cache-Control
- Connection
- Content-Length Host
- If-Modified-Since
- If-None-Match
- If-Range
- Partial-Data Pragma
- Proxy-Authorization
- Proxy-Connection
- Transfer-Encoding

Probably, this answer may not be useful for you because `Authorization` can not be modified. But still I added this answer as a viable approach.